# Excel 10 cell content validation dependant on another field

Tags: excel, validation

I am trying to validate the entry in a cell based on the contents of another cell in the same workbook.
For instance, A1 can contain either AAA or BBB. I am entering data in A2.

If cell A1 contains AAA, then the entry in cell A2 has to be greater than 6.
If cell A1 contains BBB, then the entry in cell A2 has to be greater than 14.

I tried to use custom validation & validation based on a formulae but I cant get either to work how I want them to.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom validation formula would be:

```
=OR(AND(A1="BBB",A2>14),AND(A1="AAA",A2>6))
```

Be sure to include a helpful error message.

Comment: If you have more codes than just AAA and BBB, you can always create a VBA function to check the values, and reference that instead of using a direct formula.

Comment: Thanks, the formula will do just fine.  I do have 4 base values but I can extend the "AND"s.  Thanks again